# Hibernate @ManyToMany -- join table isn't being populated

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement a @ManyToMany relationship, but my join table isn't being populated.  My app models a bunch of Competition objects to Competitor objects.  There is a group of Competitors.  Within that group, each Competitor is matched with each other Competitor to form a Competition.  So each Competition can have a list of Competitor objects.  And each Competitor can be in multiple Competitions.

**Entity Objects**

Competition looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "competition")
public class Competition implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int competitionId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "competition_competitors", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "competitionId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "competitorId"))
    private Set<Competitor> competitors = new TreeSet<Competitor>();

            . . .
```

My competitor object looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "competitor")
public class Competitor implements Comparable<Competitor>, java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int competitorId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "competitors", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Competition> competitions = new TreeSet<Competition>();

            . . .
```

**CompetitionService Method**

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public Competition createCompetition(League league, Competitor competitor1, Competitor competitor2) {
    Competition competition = getCompetitionDAO().create(league);
    competition.add(competitor1);
    competition.add(competitor2);
    this.competitionDao.saveOrUpdate(competition);
    return competition;
}
```

**CompetitionDAO Method**

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void saveOrUpdate(Competition competition) {
    if (competition != null) {
        Session session = getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.saveOrUpdate(competition);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new AppException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

**Application Code**

This code should create a competition and persist it.  It used to do that, but somewhere along the line I broke it, and it no longer saves anything to the join table {competition_competitors}.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
private void createLeague(LeagueData leagueData) {

    User user = createAccount( ... );
    League league = createLeague(user, leagueData.getLeagueName());

    for (int index = 0; index < leagueData.getCompetitorNames().length; index++) {
        Competitor competitor = this.serviceProvider.getCompetitorService().find(league, leagueData.getCompetitorNames()[index]);
        if (competitor == null) {
            competitor = createCompetitor(league, leagueData.getCompetitorNames()[index], leagueData.getCompetitorDescription()[index]);
        }
        this.serviceProvider.getCompetitionService().createCompetition(league, competitor);
    }
}
```

**Question:**  Any thoughts on why the join table isn't populated *when the app is running?*  The app code runs without errors.  I don't understand why the unit test works and properly populates the join table, but similar app code does not.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't see values in the join table in MySQL Workbench or that your assertions are failing in your unit tests.

Comment: The unit test works fine, I have 'defaultRollback = false' set, and the join table is populated.  I provided the code to see how I was using the class.  It's the app that doesn't populate the join table.

Comment: So when you are using the app, you can't see anything in the join table, even though the app runs fine

Comment: No.  The app doesn't work because the join table isn't populated.  When I load a competition, I can't get the associated competitors.  The competition and competitor tables are properly populated, though.

Comment: is there any exceptions available in your logging? Can you post the service layer code that is performing the saving of your objects

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see values appearing inside MySQL Workbench but your unit tests are passing, it is because Spring automatically rolls back the transaction when the unit test has finished. So if you could instantly refresh MySQL Workbench at the precise moment the transaction was committed, then you would see your values for about 0.2 milliseconds before the transaction was rolled back and the values were lost.

Your join table is working, otherwise your assertions would fail.

Comment: The unit test works fine, I have 'defaultRollback = false' set, and the join table is populated.  I provided the code to see how I was using the class.  It's the app that doesn't populate the join table.

Answer (score 0):

Spring rollbacks the transaction after the test case finishes. To avoid rollback behaviour use `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)` annotation over your test class.

Comment: The unit test works fine, I had 'defaultRollback = false' set, and the join table is populated.  I provided the code to see how I was using the class.  It's the app that doesn't populate the join table.